# iPhone: Stopping a Program from Running in the Background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

Right now, I have an application with a single map view. What should I do to stop the app from retrieving new location updates once I hit the home button. My goal is to make that arrow next to the battery symbol disappear when on the main menu page. The app will launch again when the user brings it back to the foreground. This is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent your from being suspended? Why not disable location updates as the app enters the background and enable them when the app enters the foreground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What you have should work (in fact, I have used it once for debugging purposes).
2. However, you should not do that, despite the fact that it works. Simply set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in the `Info.plist` file of your application to `true`.